# AS3 : How use function with variable in MouseEvent listener?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

Its usual to use Mouse Event Listener like this :

```
MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MyFunction);
function MyFunction(event:MouseEvent):void
{
// my function codes
//...
//...
}
```

but I want use a variable in my function , something like this:

```
 //var Tx:Number = any Formula;
 MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MyFunction(Tx));
 function MyFunction(event:MouseEvent,T:Number):void
 {
    if ( T == 1 ) { ... }
    if ( T == 2 ) { ... }
    if ( T == 3 ) { ... }
 }
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd imagine you will attach the listener to different button/movieclips. then, access the event.currentTarget and change the value of your variable.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doSomething);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doSomething);
function doSomething(event:MouseEvent):void {
var str:String;
if (event.currentTarget.name == 'button1')
str = 'one';
else
str = 'two';
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: Exactly right ! I want attach the listener to different buttons , then do something by each button . Thanks @joe

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you want to create a closure

```
function process(t:Number)
{
    return function(event:MouseEvent) {
        if ( t == 1 ) { ... }
        if ( t == 2 ) { ... }
        if ( t == 3 ) { ... }
    }
}

MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, process(1));
```

This will return a function from "process" that will act a the event listener and that encloses the parameter T.

ps: Even thou ActionScript allows hoisted functions (that is functions that are called before they are defined) I would regard that as bad style. Also use lowercases as Parameter names. Uppercase names are usually a hint that this is a Type.

Comment: Thanks @robkuz for youe edit and your answer . I`m a bit confused by your as3 code ! I will try your code and will say the result here...

Comment: the parameter "t" didn't go into function ! I traced "t" in function , but didn't write anything in output panel

Comment: Did you try to access `t` outside the function definition of `process` ? that will not work. Closure parameters are not visible outside of the defining closure.